# Форма на php выдаёт ошибку

Tags: php, html-form

Форма: 2 поля и одна радио-кнопка. **Update**: проблема решена, см ниже.

Расположена на [сайте](http://decor.wedding) (выпадает по нажатию на кнопку "Связаться" и есть внизу страницы).

При нажатии на сабмит сервер выдаёт ошибку 500. Я не силён в php, код обработчика собирал из готовых кусков. Вот этот код:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if( isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $to = 'iivankon@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Новый клиент декор'; 
        $headers = 'От: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n" . ; 

        $message = 'Имя: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
                   'Телефон: ' . $_POST['phone'] . "\n" .
                   'Звонить или писать: ' . $_POST['radio'] . "\n" .

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    
    }
    ?>
```

Подскажите, в чём проблема?

Update.................................................................................

Поправил код в соответсвии с ответами и теперь он выглядит вот так:

```
    <?php
        session_start();
            if( isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $to = 'iivankon@gmail.com'; // Replace with your email  
                $subject = 'Новый клиент декор'; // Replace with your $subject
                $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n";
                $message = 'Имя: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
                           'Телефон: ' . $_POST['phone'] . "\n" .
                           'Звонить или писать: ' . $_POST['radio'] . "\n" ;

                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    
            }
    ?>
```

Сервер ошибку не выдаёт, однако на почту ничего не приходит и на самом сайте никакого подтверждения об отправке формы не появляется. Где искать проблему?

Update.................................................................................

Проблема решилась. Всем спасибо за помощь! 
Вот это условие оказалось, во-первых, лишним, а во-вторых, всегда false:

```
session_start();
if( isset($_POST['submit']))
{}
```

Comment: Добавте, что стоит в логах веб-сервера.

Comment: В логах были такие ошибки: decor.wedding [Sun Apr 23 16:23:07 201] [error] [client 95.72.220.208] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/srv66214/decor.wedding/php/process.php on line 7, referer: http://decor.wedding/
decor.wedding [Sun Apr 23 16:50:45 201] [error] [client 195.170.42.207] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$message' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/srv66214/decor.wedding/php/process.php on line 9, referer: http://decor.wedding/ - это поправил, теперь всё равно ничего не работает, но в логах новых ошибок не появляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ещё не работает отправка, то попробуйте выполнить простую отправку письма на свою почту кодом:

```
mail("iivankon@gmail.com", "My Subject", "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3");
```

Если и эта команда не заработает (не забудьте в спаме проверить письмо), то тут уже нужно настраивать сервер.

Answer (score 2):

После заполнения переменной `$message` поставьте точку с запятой, у вас сейчас там точка.
Также поправьте этот код

```
 $headers = 'От: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n" . ;
```

на

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n";
```

Переводить слово "From" в headers не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, это поправил, но теперь всё равно ничего не работает. Есть ещё предположения, что можно исправить?

Comment: Вы код здесь поправте тоже. Откуда идеям взяться, если здесь не рабочий код. "Ничего не работает" -  поясните.